# How to use bloc pattern with inappview plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am using inappview in my flutter app, each time the request url is different.
I applied bloc pattern in my application, can I use bloc builder to pass the url to the plugin?

Comment: What do you mean 'pass the URL to the plugin'? Please, add some information or example.

Comment: kindly find the below example, the URL every time is variable, I built it using different parameters each time:

InAppWebView(
                        key: webViewKey,
                        initialUrlRequest:
                        URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(URL)),
                       onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                          webViewController = controller;
                        })

Answer (score 0):

You can pass initialUrlRequest 'about:blank' and after initialize webViewController use below code every need to load different url.

```dart
webViewController.loadUrl(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(dynamicURL)));
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, i build the dynamic url according to event, 
ex: when I click btn, I must build the url and pass it to the inappview
can i use bloc builder to pass the dynamic url?

Comment: Yes you can use but unnecassary. If the code I gave is added to onTap, you will get what you want. But if you want this code in BLOC, you should pass webViewController to your bloc constructor. So you don't need BlocBuilder to update webview content.

Comment: kindly could you explain where is "onTop" ?

Comment: By onTap I mean your url change event. It could be a button click, or it could be your own logic inside the bloc.

Comment: Sorry I confused  little bit, you said "So you don't need BlocBuilder to update webview content", the intial state of webview is "about:blank", after event happen from other widget I need to update state and pass new url to inappwebview, so i need bloc builder to rebuild the widget with new url.. is that right?

Comment: After event happen you don't need to update the state, because loadUrl function send new event to native code with MethodChannel so update state on the native side.

Comment: but need to update the url

Comment: You should use 'BlocListener' to update URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238107/discussion-between-nmma-and-salih-can).